# Git Command for displaying a list

Tags: git, gradle

My requirement is to capture the commit messages between two tags and I want to use grgit plugin to achieve this. Now, there is a documentation provided for [grgit](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/index.html?org/ajoberstar/grgit/Grgit.html) and I am using Log operation to get a log of commit between two tags. I am writing this inside a task and ec=ecuting from command prompt. My task looks like this :

```
task showLog <<{
   def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: 'C:\\Rep9')
   def history = grgit.log()
}
```

and executing task like gradlew showLog. My task says *BUILD SUCCESSFUL* ,but I am unable to see the log anywhere. I want to see the entire log and may be use (I am not sure) some other operation to capture my messages, If anybody could help , would be really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke `log()` on `grgit` object, then via [`LogOp`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/LogOp.groovy) you'll get a list of [`Commit`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/ajoberstar/grgit/Commit.groovy) objects. Then you can just iterate over this objects and using `findAll` or `grep` find what you need.

When it comes to tags, you might operate on them using [`TagService`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/ajoberstar/grgit/service/TagService.groovy). To get an instance of the mentioned service invoke `grgit.tag` and then [via `list()`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/TagListOp.groovy) operation a list of [`Tag`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/ajoberstar/grgit/Tag.groovy) is fetched. Use it to find tags you are interested in.

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34847832)'s a demo.

And the relevant part:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.4.1'
  }
}

import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

task showLog <<{
  def grgit = project.file('so').exists() ? Grgit.open('so') : Grgit.clone(dir: 'so', uri: 'git@github.com:Opalo/stackoverflow.git')
  def log = grgit.log()

  log.each { l ->
    logger.lifecycle("ID: $l.id, Author: $l.author")
  }

  grgit.tag.list().each { t ->
    logger.lifecycle("Commit: $t.commit.id, tagger: $t.tagger.email")
  }
}
```

Comment: If I want to get all the commits in between two tags, tag1 and tag2 , can I write my log operation as :  def log = grgit.log{  range tag2, tag1 }

Comment: No, you can't. You need to fetch all the tags/commits and filter them in your script.

Comment: Ok, I will try this demo. Well, in the demo above, we are trying to iterate to the list of commits/tags that we fetch. right? But, what exactly does 1- > /t -> is? I just didn't understand that.

Comment: @Sakshi, this is a groovy stuff. A replacement for `it`. You can use `it.id` or `l ->` and `l.id`.

Comment: this worked, I can see all the tags and logs. Thanks a lot for this solution :) I am actually learning groovy so I have just one more thing to ask. How can I link my tag name with the commit. As in, in between two tags what all commits I have made, I need to get them in some variable.

Comment: @Sakshi as you can see [here](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/ajoberstar/grgit/Tag.groovy) a `Tag` already has a relation to particular commit. Use it. If my answer solved the problem, please accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100979/discussion-between-sakshi-and-opal).